# Do all heirs have to sign to sell inherited real estate In West Virginia?

Tags: trusts-and-estates

My Mother passed away and named five beneficiaries in her will.  Before her house was sold, my sister, one of the five, passed away intestate. She has two adult children. Now, my sister’s son is refusing to sign to sell my mother’s house. Can my mother’s Executor sell the house without my nephew’s signature? (My nephew's share of the house is 10%, and the rest of us own 20% each.)

Answer (score 3):

### If the estate has not been settled, yes

The executor is the legal owner of the house and does not need the beneficiaries' permission to sell it if they decide that is in the beneficiaries' best interests. They can consider their wishes, but they don't have to, and they don't have to follow them if they do.

Comment: Of course, if the nephew disagrees with the executor as to what is in the beneficiaries best interests it is open to the nephew to sue the executor.  (Your answer could be read as implying the executor has _carte blanche_ to do whatever they think is best.)

Comment: Ultimately a partition sale can be requested, and will proceed over the objections of one of the part-owners.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on state law and the terms of the will, among other things. [In Florida](https://www.gibbslawfl.com/tenancy-in-common-and-florida-estate-planning/), by default tenancies are tenancy in common. It is possible to make it be a joint tenancy with right of survivorship, but you have to explicitly say this. The children of the deceased beneficiary might be effectively disinherited (that's why "with right of survivorship" is crucial).
The heir of a tenant in common receives the decedent owner’s share, and all rights attached to that interest. In that case the uncooperative person can complicate the process. You might be forced to file a partition suit, which would result in a court-supervised sale (not an economically advisable outcome).